# Is it possible to extend a whole android app?

Tags: android, oop

Is it possible to create a project `com.example.masterprojects.foo`, define it's activities, layouts, drawables, etc. And, later, create a `com.example.clientprojects.bar` that extends everything in Foo, only overwritting the drawables?

Im creating a project that will be the same look and feel for 3 friends, but I'll have three final apps.

Comment: Yes, you could create a master project as a library and then use this library in 3 projects.

Comment: If the only difference between the apps is the drawables, the most sensible thing I can think of is have 1 app and just load the different drawables from image files.

Comment: @Szymon But libraries can even have activities? I tought was limited to some classes... Any docs you can suggest?

Comment: @Squonk it would make the app size grow too much.

Comment: Yes, they have everything. I built my apps this way, it works well. I created activities, resources, etc in the library and inherited some activities to change them in apps, defined more resources,  etc. I'll try to find some docs.

Comment: I really appretiate it. Im still learning android and this project will be my challenge :)